# Unpack string into one/two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I'm looking for a way to split a string into one or two variables.

```
string1 = "one,two"
string2 = "one"
var1, var2 = string1.split(",")
var1, var2 = string2.split(",")
```

Expected outcome

```
var1="one" var2="two"
var1="one" var2=None
```

Somewhat like `.get("value", "default value")` setting a default value to `None` to avoid `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

I know that I can do

```
if "," in string: 
    split twice 
else: 
    split once
```

but I'm trying to find a better way of handling this

Working with pyhton3

Comment: Please define "better"; your stated problem is, at its core, the straightforward `if` that you outlined.  Python does not supply such a facility.  If you want such a facility, you're welcome to write the function, extending this to a length of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `var2` a *list* of remaining values to unpack. That list will be empty if `split` doesn't produce enough values.

```
var1, *var2 = "one".split(",")
assert var1 == "one"
assert var2 == []
```

The `*`ed variable must be the last name in the list, but otherwise there is no limit on how many leading values you can unpack individually before collecting the remaining values.

Comment: Thanks works perfect in my case as var1 is an aws ec2 tag name and anything in var2 are the tag values I want my describe_instances call to filter.

Answer (score 2):

To get such result you could do:

```
string2 = "one"
var1, var2 = (string2.split(",")+[None])[:2]
print(var1) #one
print(var2) #None
```

I simply add `None` at end of `list` produced by `.split` and then gets first 2 elements using `slice`, therefore I always get 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function for printing with desired string as parameter of the function.

```
def req_print(string):
    if string != ',':
       print(var)
    else:
       var1, var2 = string.split(',')
       print(var1, var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator assignment:

```
temp = 'one, two'.split(", ")

var1, var2 = temp if len(temp) == 2 else (temp[0], None)
print(var1, var2)
# one two

temp = 'one'.split(", ")

var1, var2 = temp if len(temp) == 2 else (temp[0], None)
print(var1, var2)
# one None
```